# How to call JavaScript function from ajax return

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, function

I have a $.POST call that return the name of a function that need to be ran but it wont execute the function and I don't know why.

Here is an example:

JS file:

```
$(function(){
     $.post('test.php',{event: 'add'},
          function(data){
               data.func(data.msg);
          },'json');

     function test(msg){
          alert(msg);
     }
});
```

PHP Ajax:

```
<?php
     switch($_POST['event']){
          case 'add':
               $output['func'] = 'test';
               $output['msg'] = 'This is add message';
               break;
          case 'delete':
               $output['func'] = 'test';
               $output['msg'] = 'This is delete message';
               break;
     }
     echo json_encode($output);
 ?>
```

The problem I am having is the ajax is returning the name of the function (test) but it will not run the function, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DO NOT USE EVAL.**

Rather, make an object with the functions you want to be executable.  For example:

```
var functionTable = {
    test: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
};

$.post('test.php', { event: 'add' }, function (data) {
    if (functionTable.hasOwnProperty(data.func)) {
        functionTable[data.func](data.msg);
    }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly the same as I have ;) +1

Comment: @Harmen, Yup, I saw that soon after I posted my answer.  I prefer to use `hasOwnProperty`, however.  (Who knows; someone may add a dangerous function to `Object.prototype` which gets called remotely...

Comment: Eval() is only as "evil" as your usage of it.  If he's generating that JSON in a way that's isolated from user generated data (which it appears he is), there's not much pragmatic reason to avoid eval().  It's particularly unnecessary to avoid it in this case, because $.post will already be using an eval() derivative to deserialize the JSON response in all but the most current browsers anyway.

Comment: @Dave Ward, jQuery will use the JSON.parse() function to parse JSON. And still, you cannot be sure that the output is a JSON structure with a func and msg key

Comment: @Harmen: Only in newer browsers that have implemented that. There are still an awful lot of browsers currently in use (anything below IE8, Firefox 3.5, Chrome 3, and Safari 5, I believe) that don't implement JSON.parse natively. In those browsers, jQuery uses `new Function(json)` to deserialize JSON, which is effectively an eval().

Comment: @Dave Ward, It is a very good practice to always avoid eval unless you *know with absolute certainty* it is required (besides injecting a `<script>`).

Comment: Definitely, you have to be mindful when using eval(). However, in this case, it's only dangerous if his server is compromised and an attacker could modify the PHP. Of course, in that case, he's got *much* bigger problems than eval(), and no attacker would waste time injecting script in the JSON when they could just inject their own arbitrary script on the site. It seems a bit excessive that thejh got two downvotes just for daring to mention eval(), when it's perfectly valid in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to move your function into an object here, so you can see if it exists or not:

```
var possibleFunctions = {
  test: function(val){
    alert(val);
  }
};

$(function(){
     $.post('test.php',{event: 'add'},
          function(data){
              if(possibleFunctions[data.func]){
                  possibleFunctions[data.func](data.msg);
              }
          },'json');
      });
});
```